# how can fill Tagit Input from database in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, tag-it

i am using bootstrap Tagit inputs in my project. But i am stuck how to fill it from database record. i tried the following code but its not working please help me out. Thanks in advance

**Controller**

```
public function profile() {

    $locations=User::with('visitedList','wishList')->where('id',Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return view('pages/edit-profile' , compact('locations'));
}
```

**Print on View**

```
<label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Already visit:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input type="text" value="
            @foreach ($locations[0]->visitedList as $loc)
                    {{$loc->locations}}

            @endforeach

            " data-role="tagsinput" id="tags" name="wish-tags" class="form-control">
          </div>
```

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: @MortaddaJafar  all the tags(columns data) are combine in single tage not individual..

Comment: please write your output

Comment: Use `dd($locations);` in controller and display the result of it here.

Comment: Return Object 
        `[
{
"id": 33,
"firstName": "Jay",
"lastName": "Khan",
"displayName": "Jay Khan",
"email": "jay@gmail.com",
"dob": "05-10-1989",
"gender": "male",
"status": "1",
"created_at": "2017-03-05 11:08:26",
"updated_at": "2017-05-01 08:39:46",
"visited_list": [
{
"id": 9,
"user_id": 33,
"locations": "turkey ",
"created_at": "2017-05-01 12:07:30",
"updated_at": "2017-05-01 12:07:30"
},
{
"id": 10,
"user_id": 33,
"locations": "Dubai",
"created_at": "2017-05-01 12:07:30",
"updated_at": "2017-05-01 12:07:30"
}
]}]`

Comment: Run `foreach` loop before `input` tag without use of `[0]` and use `variable->property_name` to print the value.